# Upgrade to Windows 7 with upgrade key and full disc

Tags: windows-7, upgrade

I just ordered a retail copy of Windows 7 Professional Upgrade to finally upgrade my work computer from Vista.

It's not scheduled to be delivered until Monday, though, and I was hoping to take my computer home and upgrade over the weekend. I already have a full retail (non-upgrade) disc for the same edition that I'd bought for myself, though.

*So can I use that disc to perform the install, and then just enter my upgrade key on Monday when it comes in?* Will that make everything activate properly? Or do I need to wait till I get my actual upgrade-specific disc before I try to use my upgrade-specific key?

Comment: I don't know for sure but one would assume the key is different since it is a discounted upgrade version.

Comment: Why would you not just use the key with the "same edition" that you purhcased?

Comment: @Chris: I'm trying to using the disc from my personal copy (already installed and activated on my computer at home) to perform the physical installation only, then use the upgrade key that will be arriving in the mail on Monday to activate.

Comment: I tried installing an upgrade key with a fresh install, (wiped the pc and installed it) and it didn't work. Said that the windows wasn't properly activated. I would wait :(

Comment: If you do that you will have a key defined during install, and then have to change it to upgrade key.  But why do this is the part I do not understand.  Is it you just do not want to wait ?

Comment: @Chris: pretty much, yeah.

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me.  Not sure it will work if they are different versions, but if they are the same version, then yes, you can install the copy you have and change the key later:

[How to Change Windows 7 Product Key](http://www.blogsdna.com/2233/how-to-change-windows-7-product-key.htm)